# What is actually happening with IQueryable.Where()?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, iqueryable

This is is returning a boolean based on whether or not there are some matching IDs.

```
from t in getAll
select new Result
{
...             
    bool DetailsAvailable = 
        (db.SaveTrackings.Where(s => s.BundleID == t.bundleID 
                                  && s.UserID == t.userID)
                         .Count() > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

This is what I think understand: `.Where()` is returning all the entries with the matching IDs and then the `.Count()` is just seeing how many are there. I only feel like I half understand what we need `s` for.

I know what to expect from this code since it's been in use I just don't understand how it works and some of the documentation from MSDN is using some terminology that is confusing me.

> All lambda expressions use the lambda
>   operator =>, which is read as "goes
>   to". The left side of the lambda
>   operator specifies the input
>   parameters (if any) and the right side
>   holds the expression or statement
>   block. The lambda expression x => x *
>   x is read "x goes to x times x."

So how am I suppose to understand what my code means based on this, `.Where(s` "goes to" `s.BundleID == t.BundleID`...) so what's happening here? What does "goes to" mean? Is it comparing every ID in `s` to everyone one available in `t`? How do I understand why it's called "goes to" and what exactly is happening?

And then it gets more confusing...

> The => operator has the same
>   precedence as assignment (=) and is
>   right-associative.
>
> Lambdas are used in method-based LINQ
>   queries as arguments to standard query
>   operator methods such as Where.
>
> When you use method-based syntax to
>   call the Where method in the
>   Enumerable class (as you do in LINQ to
>   Objects and LINQ to XML) the parameter
>   is a delegate type System.Func. A lambda expression is the
>   most convenient way to create that
>   delegate.

What is a delegate type `System.Func<T, TResult>` and how is it created with this "goes to" operator?

I can't just use code because I know that it's working, I need to understand how/why.

Comment: if you really just need a true or false, it might be more effective to use the Any function instead of where+count? db.SaveTrackings.Any( same predicate) will return true as soon as one item is true.

Comment: it will take a little while, then it will just "click".  the simplest way is to just think of them as mini-functions with no names.  the syntax can be a little wierd, especially with no args... () => { blah blah blah } gets everyone the first time.  WTH IS THAT THING!!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would help to see this function implemented by hand:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharpSandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            foreach (T item in input)
            {
                if (predicate(item))
                    yield return item;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            IEnumerable<int> evens = Where(numbers, n => n % 2 == 0);
            foreach (int even in evens)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(even);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The construct `name => someEvaluation` creates an anonymous function consisting of the following parts:

- `name` is simply the name of a parameter, its type is inferred from its usage. You need a name so you can refer to the argument passed in the function.
- `=>` is the start of your anonymous functions body, the scope of the body is a single expression.
- `someEvaluation` is the body of your anonymous function composed of a single expression.

In our case, `Func<T, bool>` defines a function which takes a single parameter of type `T` and returns an output of type `bool`. (If we had used `Func<T, U, bool>`, we'd take two inputs of type `T` and `U` and return a `bool`. The last type parameter in the `Func` definition is the return value.)

You can invoke an instance of `Func` exactly as you invoke any other function. If the func takes params, you pass them in as expected, your parameters are bound to the variable names you defined. When you invoke the function, control flow will jump inside your function and evaluate its results.

In principle, you don't need to create a `Func` anonymously. You can pass in any function which has a compatible type signature, such as:

```
    static bool IsEven(int n)
    {
        return n % 2 == 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        IEnumerable<int> evens = Where(numbers, IsEven);
        foreach (int even in evens)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(even);
        }
    }
```

This program produces the same output. In fact, behind the scenes, the syntax `name => expression` is syntax sugar; when it gets compiled, C# will produce a produce a private function with a hidden name and convert it to the format above.

Comment: Maybe this would help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294053/explaining-functional-programming-to-object-oriented-programmers-and-less-technic/2294279#2294279

Comment: Hold on a second. With your first example you wrote out a function. Is this just to demonstrate what is happening or is this really how this thing is implemented? Because I get what is happening I just don't get how. For example if I do a cout>> the computer tells the graphics card to spit out the text to my monitor. However I don't know HOW these things are happening, I just know that they work.

Comment: @Ryan: yes, the function above really *is* how you'd implement the Where function. Its not clear what part you don't understand. For what its worth, most C# is full of syntax sugar which can occasionally obscure the underlying implementation details. A function containing `yield return whatever` is converted into a class implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, which itself is a state machine which moves to the next step everytime you call its Enumerator's `MoveNext()` function. (...)

Comment: (...) `foreach` is unwrapped expands into a `IEnumerator enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator(); try { ... } finally { enumerator.Dispose(); }`. And `parameter => expr` expands the anonymous function into a private class or sometimes a private function exactly as shown in the second code example. And `Func<T> f` is a descendant of the `Delegate` object, where you calling `f(whatever)` expands to `(T)f.Invoke(whatever)`. There's a lot of compiler magic, not all of it is interesting enough to dwell on. Now when you say "I just don't get how`, have you walked through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Well I don't mean how I WOULD implement it, I mean how Microsoft has implemented it, is there actually code like this in existence or is it just an example to show me what's happening?

Comment: @Ryan: You should be able to view the actual source through Reflector or enabling .NET Source Stepping in Visual Studio. I can't guarantee their implementation will be particularly enlightening, because I believe they use different types of iterators optimized for traversal of different kinds of objects (i.e. an iterator for arrays, one for lists, general enumerable); and I'm not 100% sure, but they probably implement the IEnumerable<T> interface by hand rather than through the `yield` statement for various performance reasons. End result might leave you knowing less than when you started ;)

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, think of `s` as a variable of type `SaveTracking`. It's iterating over each `s` in your collection/table, and testing the value of its `BundleID`.

The `t` is same idea - it's like it's iterating through all the return collection from the `getAll`.

It's like the SQL pseudocode:

```
 SELECT * FROM SaveTracking INNER JOIN GetAll 
    ON BundleID AND UserID
```

For a deeper technical description of what's going on with lambda expressions, check out [Jon Skeet's book C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/). Chapter 9 , p 230. I found this book very helpful.

Comment: This doesn't help though because I understand that already, and having a 'think of it like this' example isn't what I needed, I'm trying to understand what exactly the computer is actually doing not what the resulting behavior is

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions are just a way to shorten the code but it does exactly the same things as declaring a method that corresponds to the delegate type `System.Func<T, TResult>`

I believe that C# converts your lamba to a method in the background when you compile and it looks like this :

```
bool LambdaExpression(YourType s)
{
   return  s.BundleID == t.bundleID && s.UserID == t.userID;
}
```